# ObservableField value changes not propagated

Tags: android, mvvm, kotlin, rx-java, android-databinding

I am new to mvvm and rxbinding.
I am trying to decouple my ViewModel completely from the android context using RxJava and DataBinding.

When I Unit-Test some code of the ViewModel (i.e. form validation) my ObservableFields does not change value and the value stays null.

Minimal example of my ViewModel:

```
class RegistrationViewModel(var validator: Validator) : ViewModel {

    val username: ObservableField<String> = ObservableField()
    val password: ObservableField<String> = ObservableField()

    var signInButtonEnabled: ObservableField<Boolean>
    var emailErrorVisibility: ObservableField<Boolean>

    private fun validatePassword(password: String?) = password?.trim()!!.length >= 6

    private fun validateUsername(username: String?) = validator.isValid(Validator.Field.EMAIL, username)

    init {
        val inputValid = Observable.combineLatest(
                toObservable(username),
                toObservable(password),
                BiFunction<String, String, Boolean> { t1, t2 ->
                    validateUsername(t1) && validatePassword(t2)
                }
        )

        signInButtonEnabled = toField(inputValid)
        emailErrorVisibility = toField(toObservable(username).map { t -> !validateUsername(t) })
    }
}
```

*I expect that the ObservableField emailErrorVisibility is set whenever the value of ObservableField username changes*

My UnitTest:

```
@Test
fun test_hideUsernameErrorMessage() {
        val validator = mock(RegistrationValidator::class.java)

        val viewModel = RegistrationViewModel(validator)

        viewModel.username.set("")
        assertThat(viewModel.emailErrorVisibility.get(), equalTo(false))

        val invalidValue = "ABC"
        Mockito.`when`(validator.isValid(Validator.Field.EMAIL, invalidValue)).thenReturn(false)
        viewModel.username.set(invalidValue)
        assertThat(viewModel.username.get(), equalTo(invalidValue))
        assertThat(viewModel.emailErrorVisibility.get(), equalTo(true))
}
```

After the line `viewModel.username.set("")` in this test the value of viewMode.emailErrorVisibility is still not.

Am I wrong that the value should update itself by changing/setting the usernames value?

*Note, the function toField(Observble) is from https://github.com/manas-chaudhari/android-mvvm/blob/master/android-mvvm/src/main/java/com/manaschaudhari/android_mvvm/FieldUtils.java*

Comment: I just found out, that it only does not work if the .set method is called from the unit test.
When it's done though data binding it works like a charm.

Comment: Just updated the examples

Answer (score 1):

Data Binding attempts to be efficient when setting bound values. When a value is changed, it posts to be sure you're done making changes before setting all the values. There's no need to evaluate changes if you're still making them.

You can force evaluating the bound values for circumstances like this with `executePendingBindings()`:

```
    viewModel.username.set("")
    binding.executePendingBindings()
    assertThat(viewModel.emailErrorVisibility.get(), equalTo(false))
```

Comment: I think you mean the `executePendingBindings()` method on the `ViewModelBinding` class.
The problem is that I can't access it within my UnitTests

Comment: Any idea how to get the binding within the test case?

Comment: I assumed that there was a backing Binding, done in some setup() method. Your test doesn't show any binding. The binding is required because that is where the expressions are executed. You'll need to instantiate it with `YourLayoutBinding.inflate()`, `YourLayoutBinding.bind()`, or `DataBindingUtil.setContentView()`.